Running "dotnet test" causes referenced project to not have nuget reference?
So we're upgrading some unit test projects to dotnet 6 from framework4.7.2. But there are some issues apparently:
When trying to run "dotnet test" in a dotnet 6 project that references a framework4.7.2 project, that has NUGETS installed, we get an error on that framework4.7.2 project that it's missing an assembly or using directive to the NUGET packages.
For your comfort I've created this small "diagram":
(A, B, C are projects // the "arrow" means "references")
(project A is an NUnit UNIT TEST project!)
A (net6.0) → B (framework4.7.2) → C (framework4.7.2) that has NUGET packages
⇒ ERRORs
A (net6.0) → C (framework4.7.2) that has NUGET packages
⇒ ERRORs
A (framework4.7.2) → B (framework4.7.2) → C (framework4.7.2) that has NUGET packages
⇒ Test pass!
A (net6.0) → NUGETs installed in the net6.0 project
⇒ Test pass!
A (net6.0) → B (framework4.7.2) with NO NUGETS
⇒ Test pass!
So running "dotnet test" in a framework4.7.2 project works, but running it in a net6.0 project we get the following error (for example this is thrown in project C from above when running "dotnet test" in project A, the net6.0 project):

HOWEVER all code compiles, builds, restores nuget etc. correctly. In the VS Test Explorer we find the tests, we can run them & they all succeed.
Does anyone know why this is the case?
Is it a .net version problem/incompatability issue?
Is it a test runner issue?
Is it NUnit?

You did a "dotnet test" on the Solution not on the pre build test assemblies? Your screenshot shows build errors not runtime errors. From where do you call "dotnet test" with what parameters ? I'm thinking about relative path problems or the selection of configuration.

Yes indeed, I went to the project directory and just did "dotnet test" in that location. It does seem like it's a build issue. Which is weird, because when I build the project/solution in Visual Studio it all works fine. Same with running the tests in the Test Explorer.
I just call "dotnet test" without any parameters. I also do the same "dotnet test" in a framework 4.7.2 project and then it works! Could be a pathing issue, but also maybe a framework/test runner issue? Like I run "dotnet test" in a net6.0 project that references framework4.7.2 and maybe that's the problem

I've actually made a "fake" net6.0 class library, added some code & the required nugets that are throwing the errors as seen here above, and referenced that from my initial net6.0 project. That WORKS! So net6.0 -> net6.0 then "dotnet test" (without params) works, but net6.0 that references a framework4.7.2 doesn't work... Maybe it's a MSBuild/dotnet build etc issue?
For now a "solution" can be to just upgrade all of our class libraries from framework to net6.0. Then seemingly it works if what I tested is correct.

Might be a related to the actual format of the project files that changed a bit between 4.7.2 and 6.0. Like storing the nuget references in a package.conf vs. storing them in the project file itself and the fitting package.conf can't be found from the location you execute "dotnet test". You may try a explicit "dotnet restore" before the "dotnet test". That may behave then a bit differently.

are your .NET Framework projects using packages.config, or PackageReference?  PackageReference is transitive, so would work. packages.config is not transitive, so I would expect the behaviour you're reporting.  I highly recommend switching all your class library projects to SDK style, they can still target .NET Framework, just change <TargetFramework>'s value to net472. This way it all Just Works, and you'll have fewer migration issues. non-SDK style projects can project reference SDK style projects.

I've actually found the answer to my issue! I've added an answer to this post.

I've found the answer to my issue!
The issue was with the fact that their framework4.7.2 projects had an "Exe" in their respective .csproj-files. This was done because they used some assembly redirects (legacy stuff) and that can only be done in an EXE so I was told. When upgrading some projects to net6.0, they left that "OutputType" in there. The problem was explained to me by some senior from another team that it was something to do with managed and unmanaged code. That net6.0 projects you can't run the EXE anymore (or not with the assembly redirecting stuff) so I had to select the ".dll" files and run "dotnet test" on those.
And it works! Running "dotnet test" locally or in pipeline on the specific ".dll"-file for those net6.0 projects do actually execute the tests! And then for the old projects I still go looking for the EXE to run.
If anyone else has this issue, hope this explanation helps!
